# simple jquery on asp.net does not work on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been struggling with getting this work on Firefox. Hope there is somebody help me!

Basically; Firefox ignores the button click function and it's sub functions and the button posts the page instead of running the jquery code.

It works on IE and Chrome but not on Firefox.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Here is the output code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".CatList li").click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(".selected")) {
                $(this).attr("class", "");
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderRight_CatChanged').val(1);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $(this).attr("class", "selected");
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderRight_CatChanged').val(1);
                return false;
            }

        });


        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderRight_btnSave").click(function() {
            var elements = $("li.selected");
            if (elements.val() == null) {
                alert("You must select at least one category");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                elements.each(function() {
                    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderRight_CatChecked').val($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderRight_CatChecked').val() + "," + $(this).attr("id"));
                    return true;
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you said "it worked on IE and did not work in FF?" :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know firebug Firefox Extension? It is very useful for debug Javascript on Firefox.

Firebug also include a Javascript console where you can test your functions.

Comment: Thank you. I am using it and it gives this error on jquery.cs file when I press the submit button:

(b.value || "").replace is not a function  Line 46

I am attaching the original jquery link on the page like;
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Hey Emma, can you paste a little snippet from the html too? Maybe we can help with more info :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't check against `null` -- try to stick with the `undefined` that jQuery ensures. Check what `elements.val()` returns to start (just `alert` it).

Also, you don't `preventDefault()` or `return false` in the `else` clause which could be a reason for Firefox to submit the page.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you tjko, using alert saved my day. I was just too confused. I have changed the code as below and everything works perfectly:

```
            var elements = $("li.selected");
            elements.each(function() {
                $('#<%=CatChecked.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=CatChecked.ClientID%>').val() + "," + $(this).attr("id"));
            });
            if ($('#<%=CatChecked.ClientID%>').val() == "") {
                alert("You must select at least one category");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                //alert($('#<%=CatChecked.ClientID%>').val());
                return true;
            }
```